# How to check if a running strings is equal to a target string

Tags: javascript, string

Suppose I let the user enter a passcode that must match a set passcode.

```js
let password = '12345';
let userInput = '';
```

Suppose the user enters `123` sequentially, so 1 then 2 then 3. The first 2 characters were correct, thus this function would return `true`, but when the 3 is entered, the function should return `false`. One way I thought of implementing this function was to use `substr`, but this would return true if the user input has any portion of the password correct, not just the first to last ones. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So what's the concrete problem you are facing? Also I guess you know that this means that it only takes ~26 / 2 * length guesses to guess the password?

Comment: check indexOf function

Comment: @JonasWilms my problem is that I want to check if a string matches another string even if it's just a part of that string. Yes, I do see that the password is easily guessed, this is just and example of the problem I am having

Comment: `password.slice(0, userInput.length) === userInput` ?

Comment: If you want to check if a string contains another string, there's already [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: I don't really get the problem here. You can use `regex` or [String.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) if you want to check string partially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Jonas Wilms said you just need to check it with client type value by using lenght and check it with the password.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const password = '12345';
input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  let vLength = this.value.length;
  console.log(password.slice(0, vLength) == this.value);
});
```

```html
<p>Password = <b>12345</b></p>
<input type="text">
```